# PHP version or config prohibiting script from working properly

Tags: php, functions

I have a function that is working correctly on another site, but not on mine (the string is not being replaced on my site). Both sites are using the default 2012 WP theme and the same plugins. I'm perplexed as to what is stopping this filter from removing the specified string.

```
add_filter('tribe_events_title_tag', 'ecp_filter_single_title', 10, 3);
function ecp_filter_single_title( $title_filter, $new_title, $title, $sep ) {
if( tribe_is_event() && is_single() ) {
$title_filter = str_replace('Upcoming Events |', '', $title_filter);
}
return $title_filter;
}
```

Both sites have the same version of the plugin installed. Here's how the hook looks in the class:

```
    /**
     * Apply filter to the title tag
     *
     * @param string      $title
     * @param string|null $sep
     *
     * @return mixed|void
     * @todo get rid of deprecated tag in 3.10
     */
    final public function title_tag( $title, $sep = null ) {
        $new_title = $this->get_title( $title, $sep );
        if ( has_filter( 'tribe_events_add_title' ) ) {
            _deprecated_function( "The 'tribe_events_add_title' filter", '3.8', " the 'tribe_events_title_tag' filter" );
        }
        return apply_filters( 'tribe_events_title_tag', apply_filters( 'tribe_events_add_title', $new_title, $title, $sep ), $title, $sep );
    }
```

Comment: PHP version doesn't seem to be a problem here. str_replace() should work with your PHP version. Did you check 'IF' condition is being fulfilled or not?

Comment: @Gangesh thanks. Yes, the IF condition is being fulfilled. Is there a setting in the config that could be stopping it from working?

Comment: That might not be the case.

Comment: This shouldn't be a PHP version thing. Does $title_filter have a value? Are both sites configured identically?

Comment: @vancoder Thanks for the info on the version. Sounds like that's not the problem. I'm a novice with PHP, so I'm not sure about the $title_filter value. I did try changing the 4 to a 3 and that still didn't remove the "Upcoming Events |" string. I'm not sure if both sites have PHP configured identically, but since WordPress itself (theme and plugins) are configured identically, I was wondering if the PHP config could be the source of the problem.

Comment: How does invocation (`apply_filters( ...`) of the hook looks like? Does both sites have same version of the plugin? Taking your error message literally it means that filter isn't passing enough arguments or you assume there are more arguments passed than there is.

Comment: @Rarst I've added code for the hook. Both sites are using the same version of the plugin.

Comment: Now count carefully. :) That filter only passes three arguments (result of nested `apply_filters()` call, `$title`, and `$sep`). I am not sure why it still errored when adjusted to 3, possibly deploy issue / file out of sync, it shouldn't have.

Comment: @Rarst Thanks for catching that issue with the arguments. Glad to hear that when adjusted to 3 it should have worked and there aren't any problems with the filter itself. Being a total newbie with PHP, I was kind of hoping there was a problem with the code, because I'm unfortunately still perplexed as to why it is not working.